# Android Lollipop bind socket to specific network. What about DatagramSocket?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, bind

I can bind socket to specific network in android 5.x. 
How to bind DatagramSocket? Is it possible? 
Looking in sources if it can be done with reflection with no luck. 
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket(java.net.Socket)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket%28java.net.Socket%29)

UPDATE ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket(socket).getFd() can replace helper function getFileDescriptor . There is also new function that bind direct to FileDescriptor in API 23 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29

UPDATE: Just saw some gray additional new function in API level 22.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket(java.net.DatagramSocket)

UPDATE: Can be done also with reflection in API level 21

```html
private static int getFileDescriptor(DatagramSocket socket) throws SocketException {
        try {
            Field implField = DatagramSocket.class.getDeclaredField("impl");
            implField.setAccessible(true);
            
            DatagramSocketImpl implValue = (DatagramSocketImpl)implField.get(socket);
            Field fdField = DatagramSocketImpl.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
            fdField.setAccessible(true);
            
            FileDescriptor fdValue = (FileDescriptor)fdField.get(implValue);
            Field descField = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("descriptor");
            descField.setAccessible(true);
            
            return (Integer)descField.get(fdValue);
            
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

private DatagramChannel createDatagramChannel(Network activeWifiNetwork) throws IOException{
        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        try{
            if (activeWifiNetwork == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No active network to bind to ");
                return channel;
            }
            Class<?> networkUtils = Class.forName("android.net.NetworkUtils");
            for (Method m : networkUtils.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bindSocketToNetwork")){
                    DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket();
                    socket.getReuseAddress();
                    int socketFileDescriptor = getFileDescriptor(socket);
                    int result = (Integer) m.invoke(null, socketFileDescriptor , Integer.valueOf(activeWifiNetwork.toString()));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result bind datagram to network is " + result);
                    if (result != 0){
                        throw new Exception("Error binding socket to network");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return channel;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace your getFileDescriptor() with `ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket(socket).getFd()`?

Comment: You are right. It can be replaced. Thanks. Also found this one exist in 23 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29

Comment: Correct. But your createDatagramChannel() is still needed to bind DatagramSocket to a network on API 21, since `bindSocket(DatagramSocket socket)` is available on API 22.